# Numpy add second values if first matches 2d Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have a numpy array:

```
array([[2.   , 0.125],
       [3.   , 0.125],
       [3.   , 0.125],
       [4.   , 0.125],
       [4.   , 0.125],
       [5.   , 0.125],
       [5.   , 0.125],
       [6.   , 0.125]])
```

And I want to merge the entries together if the first one matches like this:

```
array([[2.   , 0.125],
       [3.   , 0.25 ],
       [4.   , 0.25 ],
       [5.   , 0.25 ],
       [6.   , 0.125]])
```

Is their a way to solve this without looping?

Comment: what is problem with looping?

Comment: performance issues, I will probably use this a lot.

Comment: so you want to avoid "manual python looping"? C-loops would be OK?

Comment: I don't know the difference and I couldn't find anything about C-Loops

Comment: You have a few answers now. I think you have to compare them on real data to choose the optimal code (if this part is really the critical part in your program)

Comment: I just wanted to know the meaning of "Is their a way to solve this without looping?". So basically you want the best performing code, no matter if it uses loops or not, right?

Comment: correct, but in my experience, looping is generally slower than numpy operations and I didn't want people to type out a normal loop, just for me to say it is too slow.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Because in any implementation (even some one-command python solution), for sure there is some looping behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy.bincount](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) for this.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2.   , 0.125],
              [3.   , 0.125],
              [3.   , 0.125],
              [4.   , 0.125],
              [4.   , 0.125],
              [5.   , 0.125],
              [6.   , 0.125],
              [5.   , 0.125]],
)
def groupby(a):
    """
    >>> groupby(a)
    array([[2.   , 0.125],
           [3.   , 0.25 ],
           [4.   , 0.25 ],
           [5.   , 0.25 ],
           [6.   , 0.125]])
    """
    values, indices = np.unique(a[:, 0], return_inverse=True)
    sum = np.bincount(indices, weights=a[:, 1])
    return np.c_[values, sum]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider other package, `pandas` is a good option:

```
pd.DataFrame(a).groupby([0])[1].sum()
```

Output:

```
0
2.0    0.125
3.0    0.250
4.0    0.250
5.0    0.250
6.0    0.125
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I would prefer to stick to numpy, but that is a valid approach. Thanks